# how to remove { } in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
customerqtyUI = Label(homeUI, text = (str('number of customer:'), customer) , font = ('calibri', 20), background="floral white", foreground = 'black')
```

this is my code.
May i know why i cannot combine the string and my variable `'customer'` together?

[image]
My output will have a  `{}`  and i cannot remove it

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how tkinter works, but in this case, you've passed a tuple consisting of `str('number of customer:')` and `customer` to the text keyword argument. What you really want to do is combine `'number of customers:'` with the `customer` variable. Try this:

```py
customerqtyUI = Label(homeUI, text = f'number of customer: {customer}', font = ('calibri', 20), background="floral white", foreground = 'black')
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` field accepts a string. Passing a tuple (or any other type) will be counted as `undefined behaviour`. So the solution becomes

````py
Label(..., text = 'number of customer: ' + str(customer), ...)```
````

Comment: The behavior isn't undefined. It's not documented, but the behavior is deterministic.

Comment: @BryanOakley I should've been more clear. "It's `not defined`", it could be deterministic.